# Import time when converting NetCDF to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, netcdf, raster2pgsql

I have a series of NetCDF file (from Copernicus, and some calculation) and the info from gdalinfo are:

```
    gdalinfo nc/2021-12-01_preprocessed.nc 
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: nc/2021-12-01_preprocessed.nc
Size is 512, 512
Metadata:
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.6
  NC_GLOBAL#product_range=D
  NC_GLOBAL#product_type=forecast
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Wave processed data
  NC_GLOBAL#_CoordSysBuilder=ucar.nc2.dataset.conv.CF1Convention
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"nc/2021-12-01_preprocessed.nc":VTPK
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[9x899x1800] sea_surface_wave_period_at_variance_spectral_density_maximum (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=NETCDF:"nc/2021-12-01_preprocessed.nc":VHM0
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[9x899x1800] sea_surface_wave_significant_height (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=NETCDF:"nc/2021-12-01_preprocessed.nc":VMDR
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[9x899x1800] sea_surface_wave_from_direction (16-bit integer)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

The time variable is defined like this:

[image]

So basically I have data every 3 hours and every file is a day in data.

I have the data from 2021-12-01 to 2021-12-31: how can I import this data using

```
raster2pgsql
```

I tried

```
raster2pgsql -a -s 4326 -C -I -M -F -t auto NETCDF:$f:VTPK VTPK > ./sql/VTPK.sql;
raster2pgsql -a -s 4326 -C -I -M -F -t auto NETCDF:$f:VHM0 VHM0 > ./sql/VHM0.sql;
raster2pgsql -a -s 4326 -C -I -M -F -t auto NETCDF:$f:VMDR VMDR > ./sql/VMDR.sql;
```

but the only thing that contains time are the filename imported.